# Operators bounded below on a linearly dense subset

Tags: banach-spaces, operator-theory

A bounded operator $T\colon X\to Y$ is bounded below if there is $\lambda>0$ such that $\|Tx\|\geqslant \lambda \|x\|$ for all $x\in X$.

Suppose $D$ is a linearly dense subset of $X$ such that $\|Tx\|\geqslant \lambda \|x\|$ for all $x\in D$. Is $T$ bounded below?

Comment: Are you assuming $T$ is continuous?

Comment: Yes. I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Then it's trivial.  A continuous function that is $\ge 0$ on a dense set is $\ge 0$ everywhere.

Comment: But do we know it is bounded away from zero on the unit sphere? $\mbox{span }D$ is dense.

Comment: Oh, I see the point. Surely it is trivial. My apologies.